# Maui TableView Title capitalisation?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am trying to use the built in TableView using Maui but I cannot make the title of my table view display capital letters. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

I tried using Title="Example Text" but obviously this has not worked and I have put the title both in TableRoot and TableSection both display lower case.

I have edited to show code and image of problem.

Edit: The problem does not occur on android only when trying to run on windows.

```
<TableView Intent="Menu"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               >
        <TableRoot Title="Example Text"
                   >
            <TableSection>
                <TextCell Text="First Example"
                          Detail="Example details"/>
                <TextCell Text="Second Example"
                          Detail="Example details"/>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
```

[Resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZorHG.png)

Comment: please post the relevant code and a screenshot illustrating the problem

Comment: @Jason post should now show the code and screenshot

Comment: Please do NOT post code as images

Comment: @Jason changed and noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can reproduce your issue. You could report an issue at [Maui Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues)

Additionally, as **TableView** is a descendant of **ListView**, it could be superseded by **ListView** or **CollectionView**. So, I recommend using **ListView** as an alternative. You could try using **ListView.Header** to define the Header. ListView also provides you a ItemSource and ItemTemplate which makes the control more customized. I wrote a small demo for you as an example:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Header>     
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
            <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
                   Text="Example Text"
                   FontSize="12"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>First Example</x:String>
            <x:String>Second Example</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For more info, you could refer to [.NET MAUI ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0)

Hope it works for you. If you still have questions, feel free to ask.